# For which a this series converge? $\sum\limits_{n=1}n^{a+1}\int_n^{n+\log(n)}\frac{\arctan(t^a)}{1+t^{2a}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

For which $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ this series converge?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n^{a+1}\int_n^{n+\log(n)}\frac{\arctan(t^a)}{1+t^{2a}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1.** If $a > 0$, then

$$ \frac{\arctan (t^{a})}{1 + t^{2a}} \asymp \frac{1}{t^{2a}} \quad \text{as } t \to \infty. $$

Similarly, integrating, we find that

$$ \int_{n}^{n+\log n} \frac{\arctan (t^{a})}{1 + t^{2a}} \, dt \asymp \int_{n}^{n+\log n} \frac{dt}{t^{2a}} \asymp \frac{\log n}{n^{2a}}. $$

Therefore the series converges if and only if

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log n}{n^{a-1}} $$

converges, which is true if and only if $a > 2$.

**Case 2.** If $a = 0$, then clearly the series diverges.

**Case 3.** If $a < 0$, let $b = -a > 0$ for simplicity. Then

$$ \frac{\arctan (t^{a})}{1 + t^{2a}} = \frac{\arctan (t^{-b})}{1 + t^{-2b}} \asymp \frac{1}{t^{b}} \quad \text{as } t \to \infty. $$

Then it follows that

$$ \int_{n}^{n+\log n} \frac{\arctan (t^{a})}{1 + t^{2a}} \, dt \asymp \int_{n}^{n+\log n} \frac{dt}{t^{b}} \asymp \frac{\log n}{n^{b}}, $$

and the series converges if and only if

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log n}{n^{2b-1}} $$

converges, which is true if and only if $b > 1$.

**Conclusion.** Therefore, the series converges if and only if $a < -1$ or $a > 2$.

Comment: One of us made a mistake for the negative case. I get $n^{1+a}\frac{\log n}{n^b} \sim \frac{\log n}{n^{2b-1}}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I am the one who made a mistake. It's now fixed.

Comment: I have found the same conclusion through the use of this inequality and similar passages: $log(n)\frac{\arctan(n^a)}{1+[n+log(n)]^{2a}}<$$\int_n^{n+log(n)}{\frac{\arctan(t^a)}{1+t^{2a}}}<$$log(n){\arctan([n+log(n)]^a)/(1+[n‌​]^{2a})}$